# Program-E Php Aim error

Tags: php, artificial-intelligence, aiml

So i am using a PHP-AIML program called program-e and it was going great, i knew it would be stable since it was finished a while ago, but it was for php 4.0.4 and now im on 5.0, so i dont know what to do.

the code of my foreach() functions is here:

```
// Turn this off in case people have it on.
set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);

// Can't turn off magic quotes gpc so just redo what it did if it is on.
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    foreach($HTTP_GET_VARS as $k=>$v)
        $HTTP_GET_VARS[$k] = stripslashes($v);
    foreach($HTTP_POST_VARS as $k=>$v)
        $HTTP_POST_VARS[$k] = stripslashes($v);
    foreach($HTTP_COOKIE_VARS as $k=>$v)
        $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS[$k] = stripslashes($v);
}
```

and this is the error i get on the page:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/80/8657080/html/e/src/admin/dbprefs.php on line 42

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/80/8657080/html/e/src/admin/dbprefs.php on line 44

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/80/8657080/html/e/src/admin/dbprefs.php on line 46
```

so how can i fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP manual entry on [Predefined Variables<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.predefined.php):

> As of PHP 5.0.0, the long PHP predefined variable arrays may be
>   disabled with the **register_long_arrays** directive.

This means that the (deprecated) `$HTTP_GET_VARS`, `$HTTP_POST_VARS` and `$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS` are probably turned off using the **register_long_arrays** directive.

You *shouldn't* be using these anyway as they've been deprecated for a really long time. Instead, use the `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_COOKIE` superglobals.

Finally, not to be a downer, but I would personally stay away from anything optimized for a PHP version < 5.3 if at all possible.

Comment: im on godaddy, so im using what they got, ill try the new get post cookie headers.

Comment: thanks alot, i know enough to make simple php but i wouldnt have known that those variables have been changed, or were even there, i just knew the new ones... thanks!